# Laravel /broadcasting/auth returns (302 found) and redirects to login page

Tags: laravel-5, pusher

I have a custom user `App\Models\Client` for which I want to broadcast notifications, Pusher works fine with public channels in my app but I can't get it to work with private channels.

**So the problem is**: `/broadcasting/auth` can't really authenticate the current user.

`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:client']]);

    Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Client.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

`bootstrap.js`:

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '***********',
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,

    //auth: {
    //    headers: {
    //        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content // already set in the request by axios
    //    }
    //},
});

if (Laravel.clientId) {

    window.Echo.private(`App.Models.Client.${Laravel.clientId}`)
        .notification((notification) => {
            console.log(notification);
        });
}
```

I'm using the normal Laravel session, so no `auth:api` middleware or `Authorization` header needed. the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is included with the request.

`/broadcasting/auth` request/response screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhfNi.jpg)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: @Ryan After a long time of pulling my hair, I finally found the cause of this issue. I was using a package for Authentication/Authorization called cartalyst/sentinel which is great except that once installed it will entirely replace the Laravel default auth behavior. So any request to broadcasting/auth is actually rejected.

Answer (score 3):

change it like this

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth:client']]);
```

in

`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php:`

I got this working in my project.

Comment: This makes me get `Auth guard [client] is not defined`

Comment: Change 'client' with your custom guard name.

Comment: ```Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']]);``` worked for me, using Laravel Breeze / Inertia.js.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.8

```
app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php
```

```
public function boot()
{
   Broadcast::routes([ 'middleware' => [ 'web', 'isLoginFrontend']]);
   require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

```
routes/channels.php
```

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
}, ['guards' => ['frontend']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `/broadcasting/auth` in except array (VerifyCsrfToken class)

Answer (score 0):

It still doesn’t hurt to determine whether the request reaches the route.
I checked so, I committed in

```
app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php


// Broadcast::routes();
```

and in

```
routes/channels.php
```

we had a route

```
// Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth']]);
```

Then

```
php artisan:route cache
```

And nothing has changed.
As it turned out, the problem was in the bot blocking system, which everyone had forgotten about.